# Cannot get distinct record - Django w / Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I define this `viewset` and i would like to create a custom function that returns distinct of animals `species_type` called `distinct_species`.

```
class AnimalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    queryset = Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnimalSerializer

    @list_route()
    def distinct_species(self, request):
        query_set = Animal.objects.values('species_type').distinct()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(query_set, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is my `Animal` model

```
class Animal(models.Model):

    this_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    species_type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    ....
```

This is my `AnimalSerializer`

```
class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = (
            'this_id',
            'name', 
            'species_type', 
            'breed', 
            ...
        )
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
```

I register the route here.

```
# Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'animal', AnimalViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

But when i do this `/api/animal/distinct_species/`

I got this **KeyError**:

> u"Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `this_id` on
>   serializer `AnimalSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict`
>   instance.\nOriginal exception text was: u'this_id'."

Comment: the `this_id` is different from my `id ` field which is the pk of the model, while `this_id` is another id for custom input.

Comment: then you should add your animal model and explain where this_id comes from

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trouble stems from this one:

```
query_set = Animal.objects.values('species_type').distinct()
```

Your `query_set` object now a list of dictionaries. The dictionary contains exactly one field - `species_type`

[{'species_type': 'a'},{'species_type': 'b'},...]

Thus it does not have a `this_id` which your serializer requires. If you were on postgresql, you could change your query to

```
query_set = Animal.objects.distinct('species_type')
```

Second option is to list all the fields required by the serializer in the `values`() call

Third option is to create a different serializer for use by the `distinct_species` end point this serializer will not be a ModelSerializer

Comment: The first option got me this one, i am using mysql database `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend` but i would like to try your 3rd option.

Comment: yes, that's why I said you would need postgresql for that

Comment: I have a hard time making the 3rd option, since a im new to django

Comment: sir i already define and got a species_type serializer, but it is not distinct.

Comment: I was able to do another serializer and only includes field that is necessary but in distinct function won't work. But i managed to filter the serialized data to a distinct record using javascripts.

Comment: can you post that serialzier